# Is SEO dinged if another site's post excerpt and thumbnail are used on a different site for reference?

Tags: seo, wordpress, negative-seo

I'm trying to see if what I have in mind is optimal or if there is any other solutions as I didn't see a definitive answer when I tried searching the site. The closest question I was able to find was [Creating a new site for media content that exists on another site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/52998/creating-a-new-site-for-media-content-that-exists-on-another-site) that is three years old.  [I did find How does SEO work when redirecting to a different site/domain [duplicate]](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/12592/how-does-seo-work-when-redirecting-to-a-different-site-domain) but that is in regards to the URL.  If I write a post for a site that has a completely different URL then my personal site and I want to reference said work am I allowed to do that on my site? My plan was to pull the Title, excerpt, URL origin and thumbnail through WordPress's JSON feed and load it to a custom post type so when the title was clicked it would redirect to the post origin, the site I wrote the post for.  If I include this in my SEO for my personal site will I be dinged for it?  Is there a way I can reference the post on my site that wouldn't hurt my SEO if the original origin was another site?

Comment: If you are talking about a link and article snippet, even a sizable snippet, this is done every day and perfectly fine. Just do not copy the entire article without using a conical tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you are describing it almost sounds similar to the way a site is referenced when you add a URL to a Facebook post in that at the end of the post an image from the site, the page title, the URL, and a short extract is added. If this is the case then you will not have any issues as a small extract like that and a single image won't make your page appear as duplicate content. The only way you will encounter SEO issues from duplicate content penalties would be if you copied the entire body or most of the body of the actual content into your own page without defining the canonical link to the originating article, but if you are creating your own content and it simply references the article with a Facebook style link then you will have no issues.